# How do the race traits work?

Tags: magicite

When selecting a race, they have some specific traits, starting items and stats.

Are the stats one time bonus, or are they applied anytime you level up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-time bonus, affecting your starting stats only.

Comment: It may be a simple question with a simple answer but when i was playing i had the sensation that the stats increasing every level where those of the race